# How to identify that dataframe has duplicate column names in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

table:

```
   Name   Name   RollNo   Class
0  Harry  zim    10230     4
1  tim    rim    10230     4
2  brom   kim    10230     4
3  juil   lim    10230     4
```

when reading csv the first two columns are converted in to Name and Name.1 when reading csv
but i need the bool answer that file which i am reading has duplicate column or not.

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the columns with an additional `.1` are not meant to be with `.1`, you could try:

```
print(len(df.columns) != len(df.columns.str.replace('.1$', '').drop_duplicates()))
```

Output:

```
True
```

With dataframes where the columns are not duplicated, it would give `False`.

**Note: It gives `True` for dataframes with duplicate columns and gives `False` for dataframes without duplicate columns.**

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with [`Index.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.duplicated.html) and `keep=False` for test all dupes and last test at least one match, it means at least one `True` by [`Index.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.any.html):

```
print (df.columns.str.replace('\.1$', '').duplicated(keep=False).any())
True
```